# Expectation of two cards

Tags: expected-value

I have a question and I will be happy for help.
there is a normal deck of cards (ace = 1...king=13, 52 cards, 4 cards for each value)
someone takes out **without return** two cards.
what is the expectation of the sum of the cards?
I tried to seperate it to odd sums and even sums but it is very difficult and I think there is an easier way.
does someone have an Idea how to solve it?

Comment: Try it with a smaller number of cards.. You will see that the expectations for the second card equal the expectations of the first card.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

See [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ is random number which is drawn from the full deck, and $Y$ is random number drawn at the second step. We want to find $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]$. Clearly, $\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{13 \cdot 14}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{52} = 7$. It remains to find $\mathbb{E}[Y]$. Let's use the law of total expectations $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{x=1}^{13} \mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]P(X=x)$$
$$\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x] = 1\cdot \frac{4}{51}+2\cdot \frac{4}{51}+\dots+(x-1)\cdot\frac{4}{51}+x \cdot \frac{3}{51}+(x+1)\cdot\frac{4}{51}+\dots+13\cdot\frac{4}{51} = \frac{(x-1)x}{2}\frac{4}{51}+\frac{3x}{51}+\left( \frac{(13-x)(13-x+1)}{2} +x(13-x)\right)\frac{4}{51} = \frac{364-x}{51}$$
So, $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{x=1}^{13} \frac{364-x}{51} \frac{4}{52} = 7$$
Thus, $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = 7+7 = 14$

Comment: Way too complicated.  $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$

Comment: @saulspatz Ok, but how do you find $E[Y]$?

Comment: It's the same as $E(X)$.

Comment: @saulspatz why? we draw cards without replacement

Comment: Draw the first card.  Don't look at it yet.  Draw the second card.  Don't look at it yet.  Why is the expected value of the first card different from the expected value of the second?  Each is equally likely to be any one of the $52$ cards.

Comment: @saulspatz You draw the second card out of the deck of 51 cards...for me it is not at all obvious that these expectations should be equal. Although in the end they are...

Comment: @saulspatz +1 : nicely phrased

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: do you have any idea how to calculate the variance?

Comment: @LidorHacham You may show that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed i.e. $P(Y = k) = P(X=k)$ (you can show this using the law of total probability). That means that $Var[X]=Var[Y]$. And then $Var(X+Y) = 2Var(X) + 2*cov(X, Y)$. $Cov(X, Y) = E[XY] - (E[X])^2 = E[X(364-X)/51] - (E[X])^2$. So, it remains to find $E[X^2]$ which you may find by definition.

Comment: isn't there a "trick" to solve it by symmetry as the there is in the expectation?

Comment: @LidorHacham You use it in showing that variances of $X$ and $Y$ are equal. But you still need to calculate a covariance to find the variance of sum. And I think there is no other way as calculate it directly by definition.

Comment: ok
thank you very much!